# Distance between points on haskell

Tags: haskell, distance, euclidean-distance

im new to haskell and i have to do a function that takes a list and calculates the distance recursively.

```
For example:
distance [(0,0),(2,0),(2,5)]
->7
distance [(1,1),(3,4)]
->3.6055512
```

I made the distance between just two points like this

```
distance (x1 , y1) (x2 , y2) = sqrt 
(x'*x' + y'*y')
where
  x' = x1 - x2
  y' = y1 - y2
```

But dont know how do to it with a variable list size, thanks

Comment: Hint: calculate the distance between each pair of points, then add up all the distances you have found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can rename this function to `distance2` to specify that it calculates the distance between two points:

```
distance2 :: Floating a => (a, a) -> (a, a) -> a
distance2 (x1 , y1) (x2 , y2) = sqrt (x'*x' + y'*y')
    where x' = x1 - x2
          y' = y1 - y2
```

Next we can make use of [**`zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zipWith) to iterate concurrently over two lists, and apply a function to the elements. Here we iterate over the list, and its tail. This will thus produce a list of distances. We can make use of [**`sum :: (Num a, Foldable f) => f a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sum) to sum up these distances:

```
distance2 :: Floating a => [(a, a)] -> a
distance [] = 0
distance xa@(_:xs) = sum (zipWith distance2 xa xs)
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, like @WillemVanOnsem, I will rename `distance` to `distance2`:

```hs
distance2 :: Floating a => (a, a) -> (a, a) -> a
distance2 (x1 , y1) (x2 , y2) = sqrt (x'*x' + y'*y')
    where x' = x1 - x2
          y' = y1 - y2
```

Next, given a list, a function to split it into pairs:

```hs
splitPairs :: [a] -> [(a,a)]
splitPairs (x:y:xs) = (x,y) : (splitPairs (y:xs))
splitPairs _ = error "can’t split into pairs when <2 elements!"
```

Finally, given a list of points, split it into pairs, calculate the distance between each pair, and add them up:

```hs
distance :: Floating a => [(a,a)] -> a
distance = sum . map (uncurry distance2) . splitPairs
```

Comment: `splitPairs = zip <*> tail`; while not being immediately obvious, it's a nice idiom.

Comment: I think Willem's interpretation for the <2elems case to give 0 is more sensible than throwing an error. Really the function should probably be called something like `pathLength`, not `distance`. In that case a path with less than 2 vertices has length 0.

Comment: @chepner That is a really nice definition! But I opted to use my definition for clarity — it isn’t immediately obvious how `zip <*> tail` works.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Good point about <2elems — I’ll edit that in now. And I agree about `pathLength`, but when the question was asked it was called `distance`, and I felt that it was easier to keep the function name the same.

Answer (score 1):

Without recursion it would be best to use `zipWith` and `sum` functions with the applicative operator `<*>`.

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| dist :: Floating a => [(a, a)] -> a
Prelude| dist = sum . (ds <*> tail)
Prelude|        where ds = zipWith (\f s -> sqrt ((fst f - fst s)^2 + (snd f - snd s)^2))
Prelude| :}
Prelude> dist [(0,0),(2,0),(2,5)]
7.0
Prelude> dist [(1,1),(3,4)]
3.605551275463989
```